# What changes to a humans physical form would occur if society lived inside the Earth?

Tags: biology, humans, genetics, alternate-earth, sunlight

(Mandatory I am new here, hello, nice to meet some fellow world builders, sorry for any mistakes, yikkity yak and all that)

In my "world", it has been 500 years since the majority of human society (along with very, very few other species) has migrated into the Earth's dirt, reaching to at least the end of the crust layer. This was thanks to a new natural phenomenon called Ozone Drips, which would scramble ones DNA and make them into a being of utter genetic chaos and uncontrollable violence. So being underground reduces the risk of that happening. Fun times! But a bit too much to explain quickly though so I'll leave it at that.

So they all live in a city now, and society is actually pretty stable. There are a few who risk it outside, but for the most part they're all below ground. Now, It's not all ironed out in a "that makes sense" way, but what I'm really perplexed on is what a human would look in this world. The sun gives us so much, especially to our bodies. I really have to wonder what something would look like that has never seen the sun, despite their species once depending on it. For one, I'm pretty sure they would all be very pale. There also might be some health issues involved from a huge lack of vitamin D. But they do take vitamin D supplements, so that's almost covered (think of it like toothpaste).

Anyway, what do you think? What would a human look like, with them and their ancestors never being exposed to sun light?

Answer (score 4):

##### No Different

500 years is nowhere near enough time to work any significant *natural* change on human appearance. Even after tens of thousands of years of separation, Australians and Finns really don't look significantly different.

I think it could be argued that 500 years might be just enough to "even out" the greatest of the ethnic differences of the original chthononauts to brave the dark new world. And if travel between colonies or cities is difficult, it might be enough to create localised varieties of mestizo populations.